# How to extract only specific strings from each line of a file using awk?

Tags: shell, awk

I was wondering if there a generic way to extract a specific string which by design is an **eleven characters alphanumeric** string using awk approach?
for ex-

cat ext.txt

```
This is a sample field where the code is MGTCBEBEECL for NR
This is a sample field where the code is MGTCBEBEE01 for NR
This field must be 030 when Rule_1 = 'FR' and Rule_2  is 'EUROFRANSBI' or 'EURO_NEAR' and code is PARBFRPPXXX 
This field must be 0186 when Rule_1 = 'FR' and Rule_2  is 'EUROFRANSBI' or  'EURO_NEAR' and code is CITIFRPPXXX for the NR
For NFNC with Rule_1 is CA and Rule_2 is Universal and business code is null and official code must be 'CIBCCATTXXX'
```

I want to only extract the codes:-

```
MGTCBEBEECL 
MGTCBEBEE01 
PARBFRPPXXX 
CITIFRPPXXX 
CIBCCATTXXX
```

There are almost 100 such lines from which i am hoping to extract these distinct strings, but i am at my wits end how to make it more generic and non-redundant hence seeking this community's assistance!

Comment: Please explain why there is not `EUROFRANSBI` in desired output, but `CIBCCATTXXX` is present, as both have 11 characters and are enclosed in `'`

Comment: Thats where the problem lies. there could be such alphanum strings with 11 chars which isnt required in the desired output. I m certainly not able to find a differentiator here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current examples you can do it with `grep` like this:

```
<ext.txt grep -oE "(code is|code must be) '?[A-Z0-9]{11}'?" | 
tr -d "'"                                                   |
grep -o '[^ ]*$'
```

Output:

```
MGTCBEBEECL
MGTCBEBEE01
PARBFRPPXXX
CITIFRPPXXX
CIBCCATTXXX
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a way with `GNU awk` using FPAT:

```
awk -v FPAT='[[:alnum:]]{11}' '{print $NF}' file
MGTCBEBEECL
MGTCBEBEE01
PARBFRPPXXX
CITIFRPPXXX
CIBCCATTXXX
```

- Setting the  FPAT as `'[[:alnum:]]{11}'` GNU awk can handle fields that contain  alphanumeric string with eleven characters.
- and `{print $NF}` for printing the desired fields.

Answer (score 1):

Using gawk:

```
gawk -F "[ ']" 'BEGIN{ r=@/[A-Z]{11}/ }r{ for (i=1; i<=NF;i++){ if($i~r) print $i} }' ext.txt
```

- `-F "[ ']"`  use space or `'` as field separator (to also find codes like `'CIBCCATTXXX'`)
- `r=@/[A-Z]{11}/` assign the used regular expression (because it's used twice in the script
- `for(...`  loop over all the field in a line, and print the field when it matches the regular expression.

output:

```
MGTCBEBEECL
EUROFRANSBI
PARBFRPPXXX
EUROFRANSBI
CITIFRPPXXX
CIBCCATTXXX
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any sed that has `-E` to enable EREs, e.g. GNU and BSD seds:

```
$ sed -En "s/.*code (is|must be) '?([[:upper:][:digit:]]+).*/\2/p" file
MGTCBEBEECL
MGTCBEBEE01
PARBFRPPXXX
CITIFRPPXXX
CIBCCATTXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `match` function of `awk`, written and tested in GNU `awk` should work in any `awk`. Simple explanation would be using `match` function of `awk` where we can use regex `[[:alnum:]]{11}` to match 11 continuous alphanumeric in each line and if a TRUE match is found then printing sub string for matched value.

```
awk  'match($0,/[[:alnum:]]{11}/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```